# Does recursion basically go to the bottom of a "stack" and then bounce back up?

Tags: php, recursion

I'm sorry if this is unsuitable for this question/answer format, but since it is a definite yes/no hopefully it's okay.  SO is recommending me questions that aren't helpful but are in a similar format, so I'm thinking I should be fine.

I'm working with the following code that I got from a tutorial online (http://devzone.zend.com/283/recursion-in-php-tapping-unharnessed-power/) and trying to understand what's going on.  What I'm gathering is that, from a logistical standpoint, what's happening is that the function goes 'inside' itself, digs all the way to the bottom of the chain of loops until it is fed a 'solid' return value (not calling another function) and then it passes the values back up the chain to the beginning.  In other words it dives down and then bounces back up.  Is that accurate?  If not any help in understanding would be appreciated, as this is obviously a pretty important concept to understand.  Thanks!

```
    function factorial($number) {
        if ($number < 2) {
            return 1;
        } else {
                    print("$number * factorial($number-1)<br />");
            return ($number * factorial($number-1));
        }
    }

print factorial(6);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Everything you say is correct and I need to type 30 characters.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the reply.  I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything!